# Angular/Ionic: update view with ng-repeat binds to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm new in Ionic and Angular JS.
In trying to update a collection (array) in ng-repeat directive.
That's my code.

VIEW:

```
 <div ng-repeat="e in testList">...</div>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    var param1 = $stateParams.param1;
    $scope.testList = TestFactory.getTest(param1);
});
```

FACTORY

```
.factory('TestFactory', ['Auth', function (Auth) {
    auth = Auth.get();

    listObj = {};

    auth.on('custom-trigger', function(index, value){
        addElement(index, value);
    });

    function addElement(index, value){
        var obj = {}
        obj.test=(value);        
        listObj[index].push(obj);
    };

    var TestFactory =  { 

        getTest: function (index) {
            if (typeof listObj[index] == 'undefined')
                listObj[index] = [];
            return listObj[index];
        }
    };

    return TestFactory;

}])
```

The object testList is populated after 'custom-trigger' fire: it works fine because I can see the new value in the log.
This trigger is fired at the begin of application (many time and it works fine every time) and after server notifications (here is the problem!!).
The problem is that the view is not updated. I think is a data binding problem.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to notify your controller than `addElement` has been triggered. Try adding another `$broadcast` and listener:

**factory**

```
.factory('TestFactory', ['$rootScope', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, Auth) {

    // ...

    function addElement(index, value){
        var obj = {}
        obj.test=(value);        
        listObj[index].push(obj);

        // notify the app that `addElement` has occurred
        $rootScope.$broadcast('elementAdded');
    };

    // ...

}])
```

**controller**

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    var param1 = $stateParams.param1;
    $scope.testList = TestFactory.getTest(param1);

    // listen for elementAdded event; re-get testList
    $scope.$on('elementAdded', function(){
      $scope.testList = TestFactory.getTest(param1);
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Event work and if I do: console.log(TestFactory.getTest(param1)) I can see the new value but the view is not updated.

Comment: if i use $scope.$apply(); in your solutions it work:

$scope.$on('elementAdded', function(){
      $scope.testList = TestFactory.getTest(param1);
      $scope.$apply(); 
    });
But I don't think is the best solution.....

Comment: @enfix i'm actually surprised you have to use `$apply` inside of `$on`; but it may be because `TestFactory.getTest` is returning a reference to the same object each time you call it. Thats my best guess.

Comment: I'm surprised too. In other part of application I use same way to update view (trigger) but without array, using object only. Example: $scope.obj = obj. It works, the problem is only on array of object.